# How to drop stdout in the following thread?

Tags: rust, terminal, command-line

I want to drop `stdout` (raw terminal) before `std::process::exit(0)`. Since I'm using `stdout` inside a thread, I have to use `Arc` and `Mutex`.

But I think `drop(stdout)` isn't dropping `stdout`, because when the process exits, I'm still in raw mode in the terminal.

```
use std::{io::Write, time::Duration};
use std::{
    sync::{Arc, Mutex},
};


pub struct CmdRunner {}

impl CmdRunner {
    // there a `new()` method in the original code

    pub fn run(&mut self, stdout: &mut (impl Write + std::marker::Send)) {
        // code that runs the command

        let ctrl_c_pressed = true;

        let stdout_mutex = Arc::new(Mutex::new(stdout));
        let stdout_clone = Arc::clone(&stdout_mutex);
        
        std::thread::scope(|s| {
            s.spawn(|| {
                if ctrl_c_pressed {
                    // I want to use `drop(stdout)` here to exit Termion's raw mode.
                    let stdout = stdout_clone.lock().unwrap();
                    
                    drop(stdout);
                    // std::process::exit(0);
                }
            });
        });

        std::thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(5));
        
        let mut stdout = stdout_clone.lock().unwrap();
        
        writeln!(stdout, "Command executed successfully").unwrap();

        stdout.flush().unwrap();
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut cmd_runner = CmdRunner {};

    // This is a Termion raw terminal in the actual application.
    let mut stdout = Vec::new();
    
    cmd_runner.run(&mut stdout);

    println!("stdout: {:?}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&stdout).to_string());
}
```

How to drop the original `stdout` (raw terminal) before exiting the process?

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a3101dbc45c357726762b34d6ad27e4a)

Note: the original `stdout` looks like this:

```
use std::io::stdout;
use termion::raw::{IntoRawMode, RawTerminal}; 

let mut stdout = stdout().into_raw_mode().unwrap();
```

Comment: `stdout` is just a `Vec`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Yes, in the original code, it's the real thing. But it's the same implementation.

Comment: What type is real `stdout`?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I updated the answer. The real `stdout` is of type `RawTerminal`.

Comment: What's `into_raw_mode()`? Where does it come from?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman It comes from here: `use termion::raw::{IntoRawMode, RawTerminal};`

Comment: Please remove all the irrelevant code (where `stdout` is a `Vec`) which only serves to confuse, and leave only a [mre].

Comment: @interjay I can't add Termion on Rust Playground. That's `stdout` is a `Vec`.

Comment: A [mre] doesn't have anything to do with Rust Playground, it's a piece of code anybody can run **on their own machine** given they meet the requirements (all necessary dependencies are installed). Though *if possible* a MRE on the Rust Playground of course is a good thing since it simplifies running the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not; it is only dropping the lock.

Moreover, you cannot drop `stdout` in `run()`, because it only has a reference to it, so the only way to drop it is to put something else in its place, and you don't have such something.

You can give `run()` ownership of the type, but then it raises the question: how do I drop something behind a lock?

And the answer is, you don't. Otherwise, the lock will become invalid.

Instead, wrap it in `Option`:

```rust
impl CmdRunner {
    // there a `new()` method in the original code

    pub fn run(&mut self, stdout: &mut Option<impl Write + Send>) {
        // code that runs the command

        let ctrl_c_pressed = true;

        let stdout_mutex = Arc::new(Mutex::new(stdout));
        let stdout_clone = Arc::clone(&stdout_mutex);
        
        std::thread::scope(|s| {
            s.spawn(|| {
                if ctrl_c_pressed {
                    // I want to use `drop(stdout)` here to exit Termion's raw mode.
                    let mut stdout = stdout_clone.lock().unwrap();
                    
                    drop(stdout.take());
                    // std::process::exit(0);
                }
            });
        });

        std::thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(5));
        
        let mut stdout = stdout_clone.lock().unwrap();
        let stdout = stdout.as_mut().unwrap();
        
        writeln!(stdout, "Command executed successfully").unwrap();

        stdout.flush().unwrap();
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut cmd_runner = CmdRunner {};
    let mut stdout = Some(Vec::new());
    
    cmd_runner.run(&mut stdout);

    println!("stdout: {:?}", String::from_utf8_lossy(&stdout.unwrap()).to_string());
}
```

Of course, this code is incorrect: it will always panic because `ctrl_c_pressed` is true and `stdout` was taken. But I assume this is just a simpliefied example.